# Parse nested dynamic struct to rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, nested

Section of my nested struct is like below. Having trouble in
parsing the nested structure and putting it into multiple rows. Scala version is 2.11 and spark 2.4.4. Struct keys under struct bbDemoImps is dynamic.

```
{"rates": {"bbDemoImps": {
                    "44": {
                        "imps": 0.0,
                        "ue": 0.0,
                        "demoId": "44"
                    },
                    "49": {
                        "imps": 0.0,
                        "ue": 0.0,
                        "demoId": "49"
                    },
                    "45": {
                        "imps": 0.0,
                        "ue": 0.0,
                        "demoId": "45"
                    },
                    "50": {
                        "imps": 0.0,
                        "ue": 0.0,
                        "demoId": "50"
                    }}}}
```

Tried to cast the structs to array so that I can use explode function to put them into separate rows.

```
val bbDemoImps = new StructType()
      .add($"demoId".string)
      .add($"imps".double)
      .add($"ue".double)

    val structSchema =
        new StructType()
      .add($"bbDemoImps".array(bbDemoImps))

    val v1 = v2.select($"array_field".cast(structSchema))
```

But this is giving error. " cannot cast structbbDemoImps:struct<44:struct<demoId:string,imps:double,ue:double,45:structdemoId:string,imps:double,ue:double,49:structdemoId:string,imps:double,ue:double,50:structdemoId:string,imps:double,ue:double>>
to structbbDemoImps:array<struct<demoId:string,imps:double,ue:double>>;;"

Is it the right approach?

expected output:

```
weekStartDate|demoId|demos|imps|rcImps
20201130|63|0.0|0.0|0.0
20201130|62|0.0|0.0|0.0
```

any help much appreciated.